# How to write the key/value pairs of an object to a page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write the key/value pair's in an object to the page using jquery's .each() function.  I can only get it to write out the last key/value pair however.

Here is fiddle and the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/Nirvanachain/2RsN9/

JS:

```
var defaults = {
 validate: false, 
 limit: 5, 
 name: "foo"   
};

$.each(defaults, function(key, value) {
  $('p').text(key + ' : ' + value);
});
```

HTML:

```
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.text()` overwrites the element's content, so you end up with what happened in the last iteration. Try `.append()` instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZjwWn/

```
$.each(defaults, function(key, value) {
    $('p').append(key + ' : ' + value + '<br/>');
});
```

Edit - Ricardo's comment is correct. For best performance, modify the DOM as few times as possible. In this case, you should create a variable to append the text to, then append that to the DOM once.

Comment: Thank you!  I was thinking that the text was overwritten but I was not sure how to stop that.  Thanks!

Comment: talking about performance, caching all the `html` in a variable and setting up the `append` or even a `html` after `each`  its not faster?

Answer (score 2):

`.text()` is overwriting.

You just need to save values in a variable OR append it.

Write this:

```
var defaults = {
    validate: false,
    limit: 5,
    name: "foo"
};
var txt = "";
$.each(defaults, function (key, value) {
    txt += key + ' : ' + value + " ";
});
$('p').text(txt);
```

[Updated fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/2RsN9/5/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each(defaults, function(key, value) {
    $('p').text( $('p').text() + key + ' : ' + value);
});
```